# do i need to change the owner of nigix cache files to the owner of application folder

Tags: caching, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have set up nginx in my ubuntu as a reverse proxy caching server.

The files are getting cached in the location mywebroot/cache folder

The owner of this folder and the contents are www-data and my apps owner is root

should i change the owner of my cached files to root for the pages to be served from nginx cache?

EDIT:

```
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  3817
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Fri, 29 Mar 2013 10:19:23 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
Server  nginx/1.1.19
Vary    Accept-Encoding
X-Cache-Status  MISS
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6
```

this is my response in firebug

Comment: what's your concern? Assuming www-data is the user running nginx worker processes, I see no reason of doing that.

Comment: @ChuanMa: my applications pages are getting cached under the nginx cache directory. But i am not sure when a same request is hitting nginx it is served from cache.i added this in my nginx/sites-available/default add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status; but i don't know how to verify that.am very much new to nginx

Comment: @ChuanMa:user running nginx worker process is www-data

Comment: You can use browser's developer console to view the header's value. For example, in chrome's console, there is a "network" tab. you can view the response header from there, and see the X-Cache value for the caching status.

Comment: @ChuanMa:i am not able to find the X-Cache value under the network tab in chrome console.

Comment: You can add the cache status info into your nginx access log file. see http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule#Variables. Or, I can take a look if you post your nginx config file.

Comment: Now i can view my cache status.I have ran into another problem which i have posted here http://serverfault.com/questions/494477/my-pages-are-not-getting-served-from-cache-but-nginx-is-actually-caching-the-fil. Can u please check what i am doing wrong

Comment: Checkout http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache. Nginx honors upstream response Expires/Cache-control headers. Your upstream servers return an epxiry time in the past and Cache-control: no-chache. So nginx doesn't cache it. Check your app again and be sure if you want to cache the response. If yes, you need your upstream app to set proper header to allow nginx to cache it.

Comment: @ChuanMa:I have added a simple hello world page in my document root.my X-Cache status is HIT when i take from second time onwards. But when i take mydomain.com/myapp it will always show MISS? And i can see files cached in my cache folder.Is it because the pages i am trying to cache is having cookies and sessions?

Comment: Don't think it's due to cookie or session. Could you post the response "header" of the direct request to your upstream app server?

Comment: @ChuanMa: have edited my question with response header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache.

> The following response headers flag a response as uncacheable unless
>   they are ignored:
>
> ```
> Set-Cookie
> Cache-Control containing "no-cache", "no-store", "private", or a "max-age" with a non-numeric or 0 value
> Expires with a time in the past
> X-Accel-Expires: 0
> ```

Based on your updated question, your upstream server returns an expiry time in the past and Cache-control: no-cache, etc.

```
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
```

So nginx correctly doesn't cache it. One approach is to tell nginx to ignore these headers for determining caching and hide the bad Expires headers, etc.

```
proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie;
proxy_hide_header Pragma Expires Cache-Control;
```

As this [post](http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?5,418985) suggests, you may also set, e.g.,

```
expires 1d;
```

to make the proxy cache expires for 1 day.

Comment: i will test this later and update status. As this server is used for some others applications also, i cannot do the config changes immediately and test for output.

Comment: i added proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control to my nginx configuration. Now i get a HIT.But i registered users are not able to logout of the application, and for different users it shows same page, sometimes it automatically logsout.I am getting lot of problem.Is there anything else i should to prevent this  unusual behavior of my application.

Comment: :) All upstream server responses are cached. SO everyone sees the same response. That's why you should not cache dynamic content in most cases. You can use proxy_no_cache and proxy_cache_bypass directives to NOT cache some responses.

Comment: is there any way i can use my session or cookie information as the cache key to cache a page.so that at least for one logged in session the registered users will get pages served from cache.

Comment: You can use proxy_cache_key directive to specify the key using any cookie value. It's very simple. see: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache_key. Nginx provides built variables for any cookie in this form $cookie_yourCookieName. See http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24cookie_COOKIE